# Как убрать затемнение ActionBar при вызове Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, actionbar, android-navigation-drawer

Когда открывается NavigationDrawer то все элементы activity темнеют. Как сделать так чтоб actionBar в этом не участвовал?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого у вас тулбар должен находиться за Drawerlayout. Примерно такая схема

```
RelativeLayout 
----Toolbar
----DrawerLayout
    ---ContentView
    ---DrawerList
```

Comment: Сделал по схеме, но все равно темнеет.

Comment: @DmitryVedmed добавьте в активити эту строку mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: Спасибо, но так вообще ничего не темнеет.

Comment: Вот если использовать toolbar наследуясь от темы с ним, тогда он не затемняется, но тогда onCreateOptionsMenu не работает

Comment: Добавь в colors <color name="darkness">#B3000000</color> и mDraweLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkness)); так вроде должно получиться с показанной мною схемой